# Axiom parser entity issue

Tags: xml, axiom

I am parsing a xml file using Axiom parser. If a xml element contains any html entity, axiom parser adds it at the beginning irrespective of its postion.

For Ex:.

```
<Root>
  <P> This element contains &alpha; html entity. </P>
</Root>
```

OMXMLParserWrapperObj.getDocumentElement() returns the following output.

```
<Root>
  <P>&alpha; This element contains html entity. </P>
</Root>
```

But output should be same as the input. Any inputs on how to solve this one ?

I am using the below code:

```
 try {
  InputStream in;
  OMElement rootOMElement;
  in = new FileInputStream(xmlFile);
  XMLStreamReader parser;

  StAXParserConfiguration standalone = StAXParserConfiguration.STANDALONE;
  parser = StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader(standalone, in);

  OMXMLParserWrapper createStAXOMBuilder = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createStAXOMBuilder(parser);
  rootOMElement = createStAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement();
  in.close();
}
catch (XMLStreamException | IOException e) {
  Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, e.getStackTrace(), e);
}
```

Comment: Axiom doesn't do that. But the way you're using it might. You'll need to show your program so that we can test it and see if it does something incorrect.

Comment: @kumesana added the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a bug in the StAX parser in the JRE. When `IS_COALESCING` is enabled, it returns events in the wrong order. To work around this, build a new `StAXParserConfiguration` based on `STANDALONE` that also disables coalescing:

```
new StAXParserConfiguration() {
    public XMLInputFactory configure(XMLInputFactory factory, StAXDialect dialect) {
        StAXParserConfiguration.STANDALONE.configure(factory, dialect);
        StAXParserConfiguration.NON_COALESCING.configure(factory, dialect);
        return factory;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "STANDALONE_NON_COALESCING";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is confirmed with Axiom team. It will be resolved in the next release.
For reference:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIOM-490